# websites for different regions

Tags: c#

I have got a requirement from a client. They need three blogging web application for three different regions. Each application have its own data and posts. Probably they want to share user information between these applications. User interface of these application will be same except css level changes (color, font and styles) and little bit layout changes in home page for each blog. That brought lot of questions to my mind.

**Three seperate site approah**
1. Is that good to develop three different websites for each region and deploy them in three subdomains?
2. Am I going to use same database or individual database for each region?
3. If there are three web sites, how am I going to overcome caching, session sharing and user signon(single sign-on), multiple deployment, duplication of code issue?

**Single Site Approach**
1. Create a single site, seperate the regions like sitename/regionname?
2. If it is single site, how the performance and scalability is going to be?
3. Just use singe database, that would be shared between three regions. Is that good approach?

There could be many more possiblities. Now I need your guidance that what are all other unknown problems would occur and how would I approach this problem one by one and come to a conclusion that which is best?

We may implement this solution in C#.

EDIT: The sites will be in English language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of choices to make here, so you need to get some good information from the client.

You mention that there will be layout changes between the sites.  This part right here says that you might be better off with three different sites for the user interface.  It's probably a good assumption that they are going to want to change the UI's to each site on an individualized basis.  Building all of that into a single engine is difficult.

All three could share a single database, you just need to make sure that each post, config piece, etc all have a SiteId associated with them.  Also you'll need to make sure that every query you write uses that SiteId value.  This situation is called a Multi Tenant architecture.

Caching will be handled just like caching for a single site.

After writing all of this, it occurs to me that you might be better served by simply taking an existing product like WordPress or something similar and creating templates for it for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar design-issue recently, so let me share with you my approach (however wrong or right you think it is!).  I went with a single site, single database coupled with host headers.

The first thing I did was to create a domain table.  It kind of looked like this:

```
_domains:

    _id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
    _domain_name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
    _id_category_root INT NOT NULL  (foreign key to _categories::_id)
```

This allowed me to specify a top-level domain for content categories.  Content categories belonged to the domains.

```
_categories:

    _id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
    _category_name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
    _id_parent INT NULL (foreign key to _categories::_id)
    _theme_root NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
```

The `_theme_root` field specified the default theme folder within the root.  This allows each category to (optionally) have a different css and, if it so desires, a different master page.  This allows content categories to look completely different (CSS, images and layout) or even just the CSS using the default master page.

And, thusly, content belonged to a category:

```
    _id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
    _id_category INT NOT NULL (foreign key to _categories::_id)
    _content_title
    -- other fields
```

I abstracted it this way because you can have multiple domains for the same category level:

```
    enGB.mysite.com  -> category 1
    www.enGB.mysite.com -> category 1
    frFR.mysite.com  -> category 2
```

etc

In my code, I look at the host header and pick the category appropriately, serving content and other tables that branch of that made category table.  If the host header does not match, I fall back on a default (The english site).

EDIT: Added notes on theming.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to develop 3 different web sites. The maintenance will quickly become a nightmare and the code will be very cumbersome.

Break it down into Services (SOA) Service Oriented Architecture. This is language agnostic. So if you use C#, PHP, Java, or Python the general idea is the same.

1.) Create a User Service to authenticate users.

2.) Create a Blog Service to handle storing, retrieving, and editing blogs.

3.) Create a single site to communicate with the services and use localization.

Using a service has the added benefit of being able to change the database design, DBMS, etc... without having to change the core application.

In the User Service store some kind of local identifier so that your single site can change based on localization rules. All the major languages have localization settings to do most of the work for you such as date format, currency, etc...

Note: It is best to get the Region name during the User Registration - not the Sign-In.

A design like the one described above makes the code much easier to maintain - compared to 3 separate sites.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a single site, and it should be a single database.  Scalability is a whole other issue of it's own.  What kind of traffic are you expecting?

Anyways, take a look at nvidia.com, this site is setup for different regions across the world.  It's still all the same website in most cases.  Some parts may be hosted in different countries, but they are probably connecting to the same database or set of synced databases.

The other most important thing, is do you want all the sites to be exactly the same but just in a different language?  If so this will just be simple text replacement, or your database would just be setup to where your application can easily switch out content from different languages.

Your project certainly needs a lot of time in the planning stages.  You need to make sure you know exactly what your client needs because that can often be different from what they want.  Plan some options for your client and present the pros and cons of these options.  Then let them decide.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a single site... and with that single site u can also use it with different url ...
My Mean to say website is a single and all users uses this site with different url so they fell that they have their own site .. but actually there is only one site.....with one database ....
its possible .. and its a best way .....